# How can I get decoded data from a struct inside a struct from an API

Tags: ios, swift, struct, alamofire

I am trying to learn how to use AlamoFire and I want to get the values of structures inside this struct `MyData`. How to achieve this ?

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct MyData : Codable {
    
    let id: Int
    let uid : String
    let password : String
    let first_name : String
    let last_name :String
    let username : String
    let email : String
    let avatar : String
    let gender : String
    let phone_number : String
    let social_insurance_number : String
    let date_of_birth : String
    
    struct employment : Codable {
        let title : String
        let key_skill : String
    }
    
    struct address : Codable {
        var city : String
        var street_name : String
        var street_address : String
        var zip_code : String
        var state : String
        var country : String
        
        struct coordinates : Codable {
            var lat : Int
            var lng : Int
        }
    }
    
    
    struct credit_card : Codable{
        let cc_number : String
    }
    struct subscription : Codable {
        var plan : String
        var status : String
        var payment_method : String
        var term : String
    }
    
}


func getApi() {
   
    let url = "https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users"
    AF.request(url).responseData { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        guard let data = response.data
        else{
           return
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let json = try decoder.decode(MyData?.self, from: data)
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            print("SOCIAL INSURANCE NUMBER : \(String(describing: json!.social_insurance_number))")  
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }   
    } 
  }
```

I tried to get data from an API. My data model had a structure inside a structure. I couldn't get the structures inside the parent structure but I could get the values of variables declared in the parent structure.

Comment: `MyData?.self` makes no sense. Replace it with `MyData.self`. And it makes no sense either to apply the key decoding strategy **after** the `decode` line.

Comment: At the same level `let date_of_birth : String`, if, as a property of `MyData`, add `let address: Address` and so one for each sub entity

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `.convertFromSnakeCase`, if you name your var with snake case, instead name your vars without snake case: `last_name` -> `lastName`.  Also, you could use directly `responseDecodable(of:)` instead of `responseData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert following codes in your `MyData` to continue decoding.

```
    let employment: Employment
    let address: Address
    let credit_card: CreditCard
    let subscription: Subscription
```

Don't forget to capitalize first letter on your structs, add `var coordinates` and change `Int` to `Double`.

```
struct Employment: Codable {
    // ...
}

struct Address: Codable {
    // ...
    var coordinates: Coordinates // Add this
    
    struct Coordinates: Codable {
        var lat: Double // Change Int to Double
        var lng: Double // Change Int to Double
    }
}

struct CreditCard: Codable {
    // ...
}

struct Subscription: Codable {
    // ...
}
```